# Higher categorical Yoneda lemma

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory

One of the most powerful results in ordinary category theory is the Yoneda lemma, and so the following question seems natural:

**Is there an analogue of the Yoneda lemma for (weak) $n$-categories?**

I am aware of a bicategory version (a nice proof of which can be found [here](http://www.irb.hr/korisnici/ibakovic/yoneda.pdf)), as well as a tricategory version (c.f. $\S$8 [here](http://users.math.yale.edu/~mg622/tricats.pdf)), and searching around leads almost immediately to [the nLab page for $(\infty,1)$-category version](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma+for+%28infinity,1%29-categories), but how about other cases?

Of course, the general definition of a weak $n$-category isn't exactly settled, so I realize that a proof in the general case isn't likely to exist at the moment, but is anyone aware of work done in other lower-dimensional cases?

Comment: The answer to this kind of thing is: if there isn't, then the definition must be wrong!

Comment: Hahaha, I would definitely agree!  I'm just curious as to how it is done… but… considering, for example, [Trimble's definition of a tetracategory](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/tetracategories.html) in all of its 51 page glory… I'd imagine it would be a difficult result for $n\geq 4$, so I'll probably not be able to find a proof.  :D

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone happens across this, just today there was a [new paper](http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/abs/1401.5656) posted to arXiv today proving the Yoneda lemma for $(\infty,1)$-categories using the language of complete Segal spaces.  This is interesting, since there is a more natural generalization of the language of complete Segal spaces to $(\infty,n)$-categories, so perhaps this will provide an important step in Yoneda for such categories….

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that in the references of that paper, there is another paper by the authors "Yoneda lemma for $(\infty,n)$-categories" that is in preparation, so that's something to look for, if you're interested in this question.